# Python Qt: Qprinter not defined

Tags: python, html, qt, document, printing

I am trying to put the printer to run the output from an html document.

Here is a small function to do that:

```
def callPrinterHtml(self,document):
    self.printer = QPrinter()
    self.printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.Letter)

    dialog = QPrintDialog(self.printer, self)
    if dialog.exec_():
        document.print_(self.printer)
```

However the message pops up:

```
self.printer = QPrinter()
NameError: global name 'QPrinter' is not defined
```

The printer definition is clearly inside the function. So, what am I missing here?

All comments and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you import the module that contains QPrinter? using an import directive?
2. Is the module containing QPrinter in your python path?

Comment: Now it worked:
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
before it was included only the first import. Thanks for your suggestion!